# JSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected character (t) at position 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, curl

I have a method in ROR:

```
params = "{'to':'#{registration_ids}','notification':{'body':'#{message}'} 'priority':'10'}"

system("curl -X POST --header 'Authorization: key=MY_KEY' --Header 'Content-Type: application/json' https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -d '#{params}'")
```

i recieve message: JSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected character (t) at position 1

Comment: you could try this: `require 'json'` and then in a new line 
`params = JSON.parse("{'to':'#{registration_ids}','notification':{'body':'#{message}'} 'priority':'10'}")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid - I would suggest using [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com) in the future.

```
require 'json'
params = {to: registration_ids, notification: {body: message}, priority:10}.to_json
system("curl -X POST --header 'Authorization: key=MY_KEY' --Header 'Content-Type: application/json' https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -d '#{params}'")
```

You are missing a  `,` between notification and priority. Also json should really have double quotes (see [JSON standards](http://www.json.org)) and you can do that by running the `.to_json` method on the hash...